# Derivative $= 0$ at Extremum Necessary and sufficient?

Tags: calculus

The condition that the derivative at the extremum of an uniformly differentiable function is zero.

is this necessary and sufficient or both?

Comment: What does "uniformly differentiable" mean?

Comment: Does considering $f(x) = x^3$ at $x=0$ answer one of your questions?

Comment: To sum up, its necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: @NateEldredge ya thanks, it clearly did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $x^*$ to be a point where $f'(x^*)=0$.

**Necessary**

In order to show if $f'(x^*)=0$ is necessary for $x^*$ to be an extremum, we must show that:

> If $f'(x^*) \ne 0$ then $x^*$ cannot be an extremum.

Intuitively, if $f'(x^*) \ne 0$ then it must be the case that either $f'(x^*) \gt 0$ or $f'(x^*) \lt 0$ which implies that the function $f(x)$ is either increasing or decreasing at $x^*$ respectively. Therefore, $x^*$ cannot be an extremum.

**Sufficient**

In order to show sufficiency we have to show that:

> If $f'(x^*) = 0$ then $x^*$ *must* be an extremum.

Suppose that $f'(x^*) = 0$. If the point $x^*$ *must* be an extremum it must be the case that either:

> 1. $f(x)$ is decreasing to the left of $x^*$ and increasing to the right of $x^*$
>
>    ```
>                                  or
>    ```
> 2. $f(x)$ is increasing to the left of $x^*$ and decreasing to the right of $x^*$

But, $f'(x^*)=0$ by itself cannot tell us anything about the behavior of $f(x)$ in a local neighborhood of $x^*$. Thus, $f'(x^*)=0$ is *not a sufficient* condition for $x^*$ to be an extremum.

---

Note that the above arguments are informal and rely on geometrical intuition. However, they can be formalized depending on how much rigor you wish for your proof.

The above arguments only indicate that the following:

1. $x^*$ *may* be a candidate for an extremum. You need additional tests (in particular the [second derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test)) to check if it is in fact an extremum.
2. $x^*$ may not be a global extremum.

Comment: Even locally, a vanishing derivative isn't sufficient.  For example $x^3$ at the origin.  If you add the condition that the second derivative not vanish, then you have sufficiency.

Comment: @RileyE hmm, true. Let me fix my answer.